# SAS and Date operations

Tags: sas

I've tried googling and I haven't turned up any luck to my current problem. Perhaps someone can help?

I have a dataset with the following variables:

`ID`, `AccidentDate`

It's in long format, and each participant can have more than 1 accident, with participants having not necessarily an equal number of accidents. Here is a sample:

Code:

```
ID  AccidentDate
1   1JAN2001
2   4MAY2001
2   16MAY2001
3   15JUN2002
3   19JUN2002
3   05DEC2002
4   04JAN2003
```

What I need to do is count the number of days between each individuals First and Last recorded accident date. I've been playing around with `first.byvariable` and `last.byvariable` commands, but I'm just not making any progress. Any tips? or Any links to a source?

Thank you,

Also. I posted this originally over at Talkstats.com (cross-posting etiquette)

Comment: Our FAQ redirects you to a [list of resources](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/816) for purely software-oriented questions like this.  Check it out!  You can also ask on SO--I'll migrate the question for you to save you the work.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by in long format
long format should be like this

```
  id     accident  date
  1       1       1JAN2001 
  1       2       1JAN2002 
  2       1       1JAN2001 
  2       2       1JAN2003
```

Then you can try proc sql like this

```
Proc Sql;
select id, max(date)-min(date) from table;
group by id;
run;
```

Comment: Nice...even when the data is as @jamesmartinn posted this method works

Answer (score 0):

By long format I think you mean it is a "stacked" dataset with each person having multiple observations (instead of one row per person with multiple columns).  In your situation, it is probably the correct way to have the data stored.

To do it with data steps, I think you are on the right track with first. and last.

I would do it like this:

```
proc sort data=accidents;
  by id date;
run;

data accidents; set accidents;
  by id accident; *this is important-it makes first. and last. available for use;
  retain first last;
  if first.date then first=date;
  if last.date then last=date;
run;
```

Now you have a dataset with ID, Date, Date of First Accident, Date of Last Accident

You could calculate the time between with

```
data accidents; set accidents;
  timebetween = last-first;
run;
```

You can't do this directly in the same data step since the "last" variable won't be accurate  until it has parsed the last line and as such the data will be wrong for anything but the last accident observation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data looks like:

```
ID  AccidentDate 
1   1JAN2001 
2   4MAY2001 
2   16MAY2001 
3   15JUN2002 
3   19JUN2002 
3   05DEC2002 
4   04JAN2003
```

You have the right idea. Retain the first accident date in order to have access to both the first and last dates. Then calculate the difference.

```
proc sort data=accidents;
  by id accidentdate
run;

data accidents; 
  set accidents;
  by id;
  retain first_accidentdate;
  if first.id then first_accidentdate = accidentdate;
  if last.id then do;
    daysbetween = date - first_accidentdate
    output;
  end;
run;
```